# Philip is MIA (old, trippy, scifi cartoon)

Tags: story-identification, space, cartoon

I am in search of an animated movie/cartoon that is very VERY old. I don't remember much, but I am sure about some aspects of the movie that might help. I watched it when I was very young which was around 30 years ago... more or less - I was in the kindergarten and it was the 90s. I have no idea if it was new at that time or existed even before that. I also don't remember the used language... or if it was rather in English, French or something else.

The art style was pretty weird, and ugly, in a way. You might say it was kind of psychedelic? The main character was a dark haired boy/dude with a very silly haircut, in a yellow jumpsuit. His name was Philip. He was a space explorer or something and at some point he followed his captain to some remote planet. There the captain was charmed by "space sirens" who were actually many-eyed monsters that showed to him in the shape of big breasted blue and purple women (yes, it has some adult content). Philip manages to save him, I can't remember how. At the end of the movie I believe they find a planet suitable for life and the birth of Earth happens... followed by Beethoven's "Ode to Joy" that leaves us with the ghost of Philip.

Does anyone know anything about this? I would be very grateful since I'm busting my brain to find this cartoon.

Comment: Hi there! Roughly when would you have happened to watch that? Was it in English, was it a translation? More generally, could you take a look at [those guidelines](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in?